# Возможно ли вырезать часть элемента так, что бы эта часть стала прозрачной (Скриншот вложен)?

Tags: css, svg

Можно ли сделать такой элемент на css? Задний фон может меняться, то есть этот место должно быть прозрачным. 
Знаю, что есть svg но может есть метод на чистом css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: А можно сначала дать мне внятный ответ, а потом закрывать. Тоже вариант, не так ли?

Comment: Всегда есть `clip-path`

Comment: Есть статья по твоему примеру. Не надо изобретать велосипед, если есть хорошее решение с использованием clip-path . https://getinstance.info/articles/css/making-sense-of-clip-path

Comment: Если кому интересно или будет полезно - здесь решение с помощью картинки на background и filter.
https://nimitv.com/home.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так:)
Отвечая на ваш вопрос, подобную конструкцию можно выполнить с помощью формального языка описания внешнего вида документа, написанного с использованием языка разметки CSS (каскадные таблицы стилей) и его псевдоэлементов - :before и :after, которые в данном примере являются границей блочного элемента, таким способом образуя нужную вам "вырезанную часть элемента".

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('body').on('click', function() {

    if ($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
    } else {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
      $(this).css('background-color', 'black')
    }

  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 500px;
}

.main__wrp {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main__l {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px 0px 25px 100px;
  margin-right: 96px;
}

.main__r {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px 0px 25px 100px;
  border-radius: 0px 25px 100px 25px;
  margin-left: 96px;
}

.main__circle {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -40px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.main__circle:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -504px;
  top: -440px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 109px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 500px solid white;
}

.main__links {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
}

.circle__one {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -75px;
  left: 105px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.circle__two {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -75px;
  left: 305px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.circle__one:before,
.circle__two:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background-color: black;
}

.main__circle__two {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -40px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.main__circle__two:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -504px;
  top: -440px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 109px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 500px solid white;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__wrp">
    <div class="main__l"></div>
    <div class="main__circle"></div>
    <div class="main__circle__two"></div>
    <div class="main__links"></div>
    <div class="main__r"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle__one"></div>
  <div class="circle__two"></div>
  <button id="click">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: "Ну вот как-то так:)" хорошо бы было конкретики добавить (+)

Comment: ну давайте ещё раз :) С Новым Годом! С новым счастьем!

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Это то что нужно.